# Windows 10: What is a real path to smartphone in file manager?

Tags: windows

Windows 10 (64 bit).

When I connect(via microUSB) smartphone Nokia to my computer, the Windows 10 is success detect device. And as result I can copy file to/from smartphone.

Here result:

[nokia_path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBEGN.png)

But as you can see the File Manager show in address that path:

```
This PC\Nokia C5-00.2\Memory card (MY PHONE)\Backup
```

But when I try to go to this path from console I get error:

**d:\TEMP\test>**`cd This PC\Nokia C5-00.2\Memory card (MY PHONE)\Backup`

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Is this a real path to smartpnone?

Comment: Check path from  property of `backup` file that is showing in your given snapshot

Comment: Same result: Here properties on file: `This PC\Nokia C5-00.2\Memory card (MY PHONE)\Backup`

Comment: Are you able to open power shell and cmd in that directory with `Shift+Right click` ?and choose power shell or cmd if they are showing then click on that and you will find path

Comment: `Shift+Right click` show context menu. No menu with Open in shell or power shell or somehing like this.

Answer (score -1):

Probably because the console can't find `This PC\Nokia C5-00.2\Memory card (MY PHONE)\Backup` in D:\TEMP\test.

Most likely your Windows is installed on C:/ thus you should replace `This PC`with C:/.

No it's not the 'real' path to the smartphone.